# Iterating through object properties IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, lambda

I'm using *C#*, *Selenium* and the page object model approach to test a website.

I have a page object with a list of `IWebElement` properties corresponding to buttons and links in the website that I am looking to iterate through.

The page object looks like :

```cs
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace UITesting
{
    class PlansPage
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        public PlansPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;
        }

        // Top Navbar
        public IWebElement homeButton => _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("navbar-brand"));
        public IWebElement licenseLink => _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/#/account'][@class='ng-binding']"));
        public IWebElement plansLink => _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='#/plans']"));
    }
}
```

In the test I am able to access each `IWebElement` directly :

```cs
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace UITesting
{
    class PlansTest
    {
        // Setting up driver & plans page
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        PlansPage plansPage = new PlansPage(driver);

        // Accessing IWebElements directly works
        plansPage.homeButton.Click();
        plansPage.licenseLink.Click();
        plansPage.plansLink.Click();
    }
}
```

I am looking to click every button on the page. To do so, I am looking to loop through the `IWebElements` in `plansTest` and run `Click()` on each element roughly like this :

```cs
foreach (IWebElement element in plansPage)
{
    element.Click();
}
```

I am able to loop through the elements by viewing them as properties, which lets me print out the property names:

```
foreach (var property in plansPage.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
}
```

However, trying to execute `property.Click()` gives the following error:

```
`PropertyInfo` does not contain a definition for `Click` and no accessible extension method `Click` accepting a first argument of type `PropertyInfo` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?) [UITesting]csharp(CS1061)
```

It seems that `GetProperties()` returns a `PropertyInfo` type object and not the `IWebElement` property object itself.

I can get a little closer by changing the for loop to :

```cs
foreach (var property in plansPage.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    var element = property.GetValue(plansPage, null);
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

which then prints out a list of elements such as :

```
Element (id = 8603e77b-2547-47c0-b5f9-1ea44aa214a2)
Element (id = adf114ff-309f-4534-a224-171369e09921)
Element (id = 1027eb75-7001-4dd4-a50f-1c380bfec3a7)
```

If I try to assign that value to an `IWebElement` element as follows :

```cs
foreach (var property in plansPage.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    var temp = property.GetValue(plansPage, null);
    IWebElement element = temp;
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

I get the following error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I can tell I'm close here but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

How can I iterate through properties in an object in a way that returns an `IWebElement` object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, mind telling why do you need to click on every button on the page? Maybe there is a better way for achieving what you want to do.

As for you question, you are missing a explicit cast. One way is the typical cast, that will throw an exception is the cast is not possible:

```
var temp = property.GetValue(plansPage, null);
IWebElement element = (IWebElement) temp;
Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Second way is to use safe cast, where the null (if the type is nullable) is returned in case of failure:

```
var temp = property.GetValue(plansPage, null);
IWebElement element = temp as IWebDriver;
Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Comment: Ah, that's how to cast the object to an IWebElement. Thank you, that works marvelously.

Comment: RE why I'm looking to click every button on the page, I wanted to quickly test and demonstrate that the XPath lookups were working correctly, so my plan was to loop through "wait until interactable" -> click -> driver.navigate.back(). I had already worked out the wait and back, so I omitted them from the question in an effort to keep the question as focused as possible on the casting problem.

Comment: Sure thing, question was as clear as it can be. I was asking about the reasons, because sometimes http://xyproblem.info/ might be a case.